# Is it possible to query the most recent additions to a table/column family in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Assuming the following table, is it possible to easily query the most recent items added to the table?

```
create table messages(
    person_uuid uuid,
    uuid timeuuid,
    message text);
```

The primary purpose of this table is to hold a list of messages sent to a particular user, but there is also a need to show an RSS feed of all most recent users, ie, something like:

```
select person_uuid, message from messages
order by uuid
limit 30;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Compound Primary Key to be able to sort and order by date.

```
CREATE TABLE  messages(
    person_uuid uuid,
    date timeuuid,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY(person_uuid,date)
);
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE person_uuid=xxx ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20;
```